# Popularity of ポッド as a abbreviation of ポッドキャスト

Tags: terminology, abbreviations

I know that many times loanwords are abbreviated in Japanese as a subset of their original length (ex: アイス for アイスクリーム).

Recently I heard someone say that ポッド was an abbreviation for ポッドキャスト and this surprised me since I don't ever remember hearing this word after listening to many Japanese podcasts (though much of this was years ago). Apparently it is a new trend.

My question is how common is ポッド and should I stick to saying ポッドキャスト?

To clarify, I am talking using ポッド as a noun by itself (as in 僕はポッドを毎日聞く).I think I have heard ポッド used as part of a compound word (I think there was a podcast-related site with a title like that, but can't remember it at the moment).

Answer (score 2):

This is not happening (yet) at least around me. Podcast is always ポッドキャスト as far as I can recall.

But I won't be surprised if some people use ポッド as an abbreviation of ポッドキャスト. After all, many people say ウィキ instead of ウィキペディア, USB instead of USBメモリ and so on, even though they will make less sense...

Comment: ポッドキャストってかさばる単語なので「放送」とか「番組」で済まされがちですよね…